# Get value in a textfield using GET method PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP file named "delete-wish-form.php" with a form that has the following fields:

- wishId (hidden field) The value of this field should be equal to a GET variable that is passed in via the URL.
  So my question is if the URL is delete-wish-form.php?wishId=1 then I want my hidden field to look like this:

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<title>Delete Wishes</title>
<body>  
<h2>Wishes Form</h2>

<?php

 $wishId = $_GET['wishId'];
 
 ?>

<form method="get" action="process-delete-wish-form"> 
  
  <input type="hidden" name="wishId">
  
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
  
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="wishId" value="<?php echo $wishId;?>">

Comment: Delete from a GET?  That’s a mistake. GET variables are only for reading operations. For a request that will change data, use POST. You don’t want a crawler deleting pages willy-nilly. (look up  REST). Also, starting a PHP page with your HTML output is a habit you’ll want to lose sooner than later. If you’re interested, I can write up an answer with some hints that can save some grief later

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the wishId is define in your url param to avoid thrown error in form, and use [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to avoid xss attack on GET parameter

```
<?php
  
  $wishId = '';

  if(isset($_GET['wishId'])) {

    $wishId = htmlspecialchars($_GET['wishId'],ENT_QUOTES);

  }

?>
```

and then in your input hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" name="wishId" value="<?php echo $wishId;?>">
```